# What are the css styling properties of a <code> element?

Tags: html, css

I noticed the neat property of text which is nested inside a code tag - it adapts to its containing div, which means it automatically breaks into a new line if the screen size is reduced, so I wanted to recreate its properties in a `class` and apply this `class` to `<span>` that would basically behave the same as a `<code>` tag. However, I didn't manage to fully mimic its behaviour, so I temporarily solved the problem regarding the styling of my product by wrapping my text with a `<code>` tag anyway and changing the font its size.
I've been searching all over the internet and I cannot find the source code for the styling which affects text encapsulated inside a `<code>` tag and would very much appreciate if someone, who has found (or created) what I couldn't, could post the css properties of a class that needs to be added to a `<span>` for its text to behave exactly the same as if it was inside a a `<code>` tag.

Comment: Er... Unless I'm missing something, every HTML tag ever does exactly that except `<pre>` and `<xmp>`. The opposite only happens when you apply custom CSS to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the whitespace bevaviour of `code` or `pre` with this CSS definition:

```
.codestyle {
    white-space: pre;
}
```